# Do we need to find an upper bound for the expectation of this stopping time?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expectation, dice, stopping-times

From [here](http://people.bath.ac.uk/maspm/MaCh1.pdf):

---

[image]

---

It looks like:

1. It is supposed to say 'different from six' rather than 'different from three'
2. $T = \inf\{m: X_{m} = X_{m+1} = X_{m+2} = 6\}$
3. In every triple $P(all \ 6) = 1/216$

Thus, $P(\text{at least one is not 6}) = 215/216$

4. By independence we have $P(T=k) = (215/216)^{\frac{k-1}{3}} \le (215/216)^{\frac{k-3}{3}}$:

1st triple: $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$

2nd triple: $(X_4, X_5, X_6)$

$$\vdots$$

$\frac{k-1}{3}$th triple: $(X_{k-3}, X_{k-2}, X_{k-1})$

$\frac{k+2}{3}$th triple: $(X_{k}, X_{k+1}, X_{k+2})$

Is that right? I don't see why we need to use an upper bound. I think the problem is saying something like

$$P(T = k) = (\frac{215}{216})^m < (\frac{215}{216})^{\frac{k-1}{3}}?$$

I'm not quite that's right considering the base is in between 0 and 1.

Comment: Concerning your first question: Yes, I think too, that it should be different from $6$ not $3$. To be honest, I do not really understand your second question or your objection in the upper bound (but it is not indicative, that other people will not understand it either).

Comment: @Stef 2 is that the correct characterisation of $T$? 4 Do we really need to specify an upperbound when *I think* I calculated $P(T=k)$?

Comment: Ok, check, I will think about it.

Comment: @Stef Thanks ^-^

Answer (score 1):

1. English is not my mother language, so I am not sure about the wordings here - but the idea should means that there is at least 1 number from the three tuples is not equal to $6$.
2. I guess the question may define $T$ as 
   $$T \stackrel{\text{def}}= \inf\{m: X_{m-2}=X_{m-1}=X_m=6\}$$
3. Trivial, true by independence.
4. Here is the key spirit of this example. Let $B_m$ be the event that there is at least one number not equal to $6$ in $(X_m, X_{m+1}, X_{m+2})$. Then the event

$$ \{T = k\} = \bigcap_{m=1}^{k-3} B_m \cap B_{k-2}^c$$

Note that consecutive $B_m$ has "overlapping" $X_i$ so they are dependent. So instead we consider

$$ \{T = k\} \subseteq \bigcap_{m=1}^{\lfloor\frac {k-3} {3}\rfloor} B_{3m}$$

Now the events in the intersection are mutually independent, and hence we have the result.
$$ \mathbb{P} \{T = k\} \leq \left(\frac {215} {216}\right)^{\lfloor\frac {k-3} {3}\rfloor}$$

Comment: Thanks BGM. Am sleepy now so I'll think about the indices tomorrow. They seem to be right though. So it's like: we can compute $P(T=k)$, but it's really complicated, and we don't really need to anyway because we can compute $E[T]$ using Doob's (after of course we show $E[T] < \infty$)?